# Dynamically add, compile and link ng-class attribute from another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In order give feedback on the validity in my input forms I'm using `ng-class`. These statements will look something like:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error': !frmSomeName.vcHeader.$valid && frmSomeName.vcHeader.$dirty }">
    <input type="text" name="vcHeader" ng-model="model.someText" ng-minlength="10" required />
</div>
```

I dislike the lengthiness of the statement, and would like to replace it with something alike:

```
<div validation-state="frmSomeName.vcHeader">
    <input type="text" name="vcHeader" ng-model="model.someText" ng-minlength="10" required />
</div>
```

In order to avoid having to duplicate ngClass' behavior I'd like the the directive to add the `ng-class` directive.

This [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eY4hDTPT1pMPLLIEFcvZ?p=preview) demonstrates my attempt at adding the attribute, and although it works in the simplest scenario, it is faulty and will not function with transclusion (or other more complex directives).

I know it doesn't work because of the misuse of the compile and link stages, however I'm not sure on how to actually make it work properly. Therefore my question: **How do I add different directive-attribute from a directive-attribute?**

Answer (score 0):

The elements within the transclude directive aren't receiving the same scope. If you use the angualr [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) method and apply the scope of the transclude directive to the scope of the child directives it should work. The following should be added to your simpleTransclude directive:

```
  link: function(scope, element) {
    $compile( element.contents() )( scope )
  }
```

remember to pass $compile into the directive.

I've [forked your plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UpkgmvQjRqQ3ZokiLaDj?p=preview) and applied the simpleTransclude scope to it's contents.

Comment: The problem isn't with the transclusion. `ng-transclude` handles all of that. I've updated my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eY4hDTPT1pMPLLIEFcvZ?p=preview) to demonstrate that it also doesn't work with `ng-repeat`. In addition you can see that the other element does with within my `simple-transclude` directive.

Comment: I've forked again. The issue with the `priority` and `terminal` properties is that it prioritises your directive over the others. In your example you /need/ the `ng-init` directive to run first, otherwise the variable isn't created so your `testDirective` must run after the others. I've [forked your plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XvScW5TgXwv3BiYuu55J?p=preview) again. I've commented out the prioritisation properties and added a condition for the compile so it only compiles once.